# Модификатор strictfp

Tags: java

Для чего нужен данный модификатор? И с чем его можно использовать?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

strictfp - это модификатор, введенный в java 1.2, ограничивающий точность вычислений с float и double по стандарту IEEE. Для чего это нужно? Чтобы обеспечить переносимость. Дело в том, что JVM использует всю возможную точность процессора, а она на разных системах разная, поэтому и результат может получиться разный.Данный модификатор используется в программах требующих точность вычислений превышающих IEEE (обычно, что-нибудь связное с наукой).

```
strictfp class StrictFPClass {
    double num1 = 10e+102;
    double num2 = 6e+08;
    double calculate() {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

---

```
strictfp interface StrictFPInterface {
    double calculate();
    strictfp double compute();    // compile error
}
```

---

```
class StrictFPMethod {
    strictfp double computeTotal(double x, double y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

---

В классе он обозначает, что все методы будут на всех системах возвращать вещественные числа с одинаковой точностью.
0.112 и 0.113 
Если эти числа сравнивать с точность до сотых, то они будут одинаковы. Пример, как точность влияет на вычисления.
Его можно не использовать т.к. почти все компиляторы современные уже его за нас подставляют (где-то читал такое в мануале)
Дополнил.

Comment: Модификатор может объявляется для переменных?возвращаемых значений методов?

Comment: Что означает данный модификатор в объявлении класса?

Comment: Сначала Вы говорите "ограничивающий точность", потом "требующих точность вычислений превышающих". Непонятно.

Answer (score 10):

Модификатор `strictfp` применяется к классам, интерфейсам и методам, и гарантирует соответствие всех операций на числах с плавающей точкой стандарту IEEE 754.

При использовании данного модификатора Вы получите одинаковое поведение в ходе манипуляций с числами с плавающей точкой на всех платформах.

Так же про FP-strict можно почитать в [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4).

Comment: При объявлении к классу и интерфейсу что дает?

Comment: @bsuart, Гарантию соответствия всех операций на числах с плавающей точкой стандарту IEEE 754 всех методов соответствующего класса/интерфейса.